# nice scroll handlers are going off their position in bootstrap modal popup in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a problem in jquery nicescroll in bootstrap 3 modal popup in chrome browser. Please check the attached image.

When modal opens for the first time the scroll handlers are going off their position (circle marked in red in the screenshot), working fine when the modal is once closed and reopened.

If anybody can help on this that will be great.

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a question regarding your code, adding a code snippit greatly imrpoves you chances that someone will help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply nice scroll option for modal body. It works perfectly for me.

```
<style>.modal-body{ height: 400px; }</style>

<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="invoiceModal" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="invoice_modal_dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Bill</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            body content here....
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   $(".modal-body").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#e8403f", cursorwidth: '6', cursorborderradius: '10px', background: '#404040', spacebarenabled:false,  cursorborder: '', zindex: '1000'});
</script>
```